# Can a subset of a table take advantage of inner joins?

Tags: database, join, set, inner-join, outer-join

I have two tables that I want to join. A and B. 
B ⊂ A
I filter the rows of table A based on B

`select col_1 from A where col_1 in (select col_1 from B);`

I would get a new subset A'
This would mean B ⊂ A' , Correct?  B might even be equivalent to A.

If I were to do a "B left join A' " it would be the same as "B inner join A' " because these B is a subset of A'

Are the above assumptions correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is correct and the program I used this logic for works. Ensuring that set B is always a subset of A is the tricky part.